# Strange Javascript code behavior

Tags: javascript, html

I have a written HTML form with some text fields on which I need to work with Javascript. I want to select them using the method getElementsByClassName because I don't know their exact number (so I can't assign ids one by one).

```
 <form ...>
    <input type = "text" name = "test1" class = "myClass">
    <input type = "text" name = "test2" class = "myClass">
 </form>

 <script type = "text/javascript">
 var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
 </script>
```

Using console.log(fields[0]) writes undefined, so I am not able to iterate into the node by using a for loop (it seems like there is no element into the variable "fields", even though console.log-ging it it shows an array-like structure (as it should be).
I already tried using the "form" object but the situation is the same.

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");`

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/buzb1fad/

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
```

So the classname matches up with the html elements you used.